# Convert list of integer arrays to a list of string arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, type-conversion

I'm attempting to convert an int array :

```
[array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
        1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
        1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1,
        0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])]
```

to string array :

```
[array(["0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
        1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
        0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0
        0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
        1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
        0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0"])
 array(["0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
        1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
        0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1
        0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0
        0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
        0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
        0 0 0 0 0 0"])]
```

Here is code I'm trying :

```
mapped = map(lambda x: str(x), oneHotEncodedX)
list(mapped)
```

But this insert's new line characters and quotes are surrounded by [ ] :

```
['[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\n 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1\n 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0\n 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]',
 '[0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\n 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1\n 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0\n 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0\n 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]']
```

How to convert to array of strings where each strings where each string contains sub array elements ?

Comment: are you dealing with numpy arrays? it's worth to add the appropriate tag in that case

Comment: use this as reference a = [0,1, 1, 2,2,3 ] than print([" ".join(map(str, a))])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could use:

```
out = list(map(lambda x: np.array(' '.join(x.astype(str))), oneHotEncodedX))
```

---

```
print(out)
[array('0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0',
       dtype='<U517'),
 array('0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0',
       dtype='<U517')]
```